# Virtualbox: Why does login screen freeze for Ubuntu desktop guest?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I maintain an Ubuntu VirtualBox server that hosts Ubuntu guest VMs. When I recently upgraded a VM from Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 to 22.04, I was unable to login to the VM. The server is headless (no monitor) so I use Jump Desktop (RDP client) to login to all the VMs. I suppose any RDP client would have this problem. When the login screen displayed, it would not accept any keyboard or mouse input. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is very specific

Answer (score 1):

I tried to enable automatic login for the VM by editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to enable automatic login for a user by uncommenting parameters:

> ```
> # Enabling automatic login
> #  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
> #  AutomaticLogin = user1
> ```

However, the screen still froze at the desktop after login.

I accidentally noticed that there was another parameter in the same file. Uncommenting it forces the login screen to use Xorg to display it. This solved the problem.

> ```
> # Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
> WaylandEnable=false
> ```

*Note that I have always had a similar problem logging into Ubuntu desktops with earlier versions. The screen would not properly display the login screen but it would accept keyboard input. I could enter the user and password blindly to get to the desktop. This solution also fixes that problem.*